# Page numbering in Microsoft Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to number pages in an Excel workbook which has several sheets. If a sheet has several pages, these need to be numbered in increments of a,b,c e.t.c..

For example if the first sheet spans 3 pages, these should be numbered 1a,1b and 1c respectively. But if the second table is on 1 page it should be numbered 2

when inserting page numbers using header/footer tab, all page numbers are duplicated to show the same figure.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in the "Header/Footer" tab of the "Page Layout" menu. It can be found as in following screenshot:

[image: Header/Footer menu screenshot]